# How to use Eureka Cell behavior by inherit from _FieldCell in my custom Cell class

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I notice that GenericPasswordCell inherit from _FieldCell，to take advantage of keyboard handle（eg: automatic keyboard‘s expand/collapse and return button with Eureka)

I also notice in GenericPasswordCell.xib，The only textField instead of bind with GenericPasswordCell,it bind with textField in _FieldCell.How to do that???

I try do the same (bind my textField to _FieldCell in IB),but can not be successful！

[image]

How can I bind textField in my custom Cell to take advantage of keyboard handle from _FieldCell class???

thanks a lot!

Comment: oh，I just figure out it : to cheat IB！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh，I just figure out it ：cheat IB！